# How to make Web-like options spinner with Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

How to replicate this? The Spinner does not do this.

Comment: What aspect of that does `Spinner` not do?

Comment: I need the popup and background grey out effect but the Spinner is just a ComboBox (Java Swing speaking) in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Material dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) library, it contains lots of different dialogs and easy to use.

Here is an example of list dialog, according to your screenshot I think it is what you need :

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
    .title(R.string.title)
    .items(R.array.items)
    .itemsCallback(new MaterialDialog.ListCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
        }
    })
    .show();
```